# How to test if both the mean and variance of the treatment effect is less than the control?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear, clustered-standard-errors

## Statistics background

I'm relatively new to experimentation and causal inference. I took up to graduate level stats in school but forget a ton after entering industry.

## Situation

I am running an experiment to see if deploying a different machine learning algorithm is lower variance than the current one in production. Both back testing and shadow testing (model is run in production but never used for decision making) imply that the new model reduces both variance and bias. We believe this will happen when the model is deployed in production.

## Statistical Context

To test if the treatment is effective - I aim to run a linear regression against the KPI of interest with the treatment variable, relevant instrumental variables, and I use clustered standard errors due to the experimental design. The sample size is equal between treatment and control. My intent is to run a power analysis via simulation after learning an approach from this question.

## Question

I'm unsure how to test if both the mean and variance of the treatment effect is less than the control?

My first intuition is to do both a one-sided t-test and F-test of equality of variances (by extracting the conditional means) while correcting for multiple comparisons.

Then, I consulted my old stats textbook and I figured I could use a likelihood ratio test if I assumed the treatment and control samples come from a Normal distribution. But it seems overly complicated and I'm not confident I could derive the statistic correctly.